# How to access an implicit conversion defined a class (in Scala)?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have an abstract class like so:

```
abstract class Base {
  val myInners = mutable.ArrayBuffer[Inner[Any]]()
  abstract class Inner[+T] {
    myInners += this
    def get: T
    // other functionality here
  }
  implicit def innerToValue[T](inner: Inner[T]) = inner.get
  class IntInner extends Inner[Int] { ... }
  class StringInner extends Inner[String] { ... }
  ...
}
```

Initially I had a singleton object like

```
object MyObject extends Base {
  val intVal = new IntInner()
  val stringVal = new StringInner()
  ...
}
```

And I was able to use these object members elsewhere like `functionThatExpectsAnInteger(MyObject.intVal)` which made me happy :).

In order to improve testability, though, I'd like to make this `object` into a `class` and inject an instance of that class wherever it's being used. However by making `MyObject` into a class, I seem to be unable to use this implicit conversion anymore regardless of what I've tried, which makes me sad :(.

Of course, this conversion only saves me calling a `get` method, and I can live without it, but I'm still learning about scala implicits and I'd like to understand why this doesn't work and if there *is* a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something feels a bit odd about your implicits but I assume this is just an example so I'm not going to go into the details.

The reason I see for why this doesn't work would be that implicits are looked up by the compiler if in scope of the companion object. If you turn it into a class you'll have to import it first. One way of doing that would be the following:

```
val obj = new MyObject()
import obj.innerToValue
val x : Int = obj.intVal
```

I'm sure this could be done nicer but only by changing the structure of the code overall.

Comment: Yep this is entirely what I was missing, I didn't realize you could import members from objects into the current scope.
But I'm also very interested in your thoughts about "doing this nicer" or the "oddness" of my use of implicits. My actual code is structurally the same as this (I'm specifically trying to implement a set of classes to load values from different configuration files) so I would appreciate the input.

Comment: Hard to point you to any specific patterns etc. but having these wrappers for the sake of adding them to a mutable collection and then using implicit conversions to unwrap them doesn't feel very idiomatic. The buffer being public also adds to the oddness. But if your're creating some sort of parser then maybe this isn't such a big problem.